# Line style in gnuplot for small plots with large amount of data becames unclear

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the bellow line styles in gnuplot. But because I have a lot of data and I would like to show 4 charts on the same line they became very small. Consequently, the line style loses its propose. Sometimes I cannot differentiate points, cross, stars.

What kind of line styles could I use to make the plots more clear?

If possible, I would like also to make them appear good also in black and white.

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#E02F44' lt 1 lw 0.5 ps 0.3 pt 7 # input throughput
set style line 2 lc rgb '#FF780A' lt 1 lw 0.5 ps 0.3 pt 1 # output throughput
set style line 3 lc rgb '#56A64B' lt 2 lw 0.5 ps 0.3 pt 2 # average processing latency
set style line 4 lc rgb '#000000' lt 3 lw 0.5 ps 0.3 pt 3 # 99th percentile processing latency
set style line 5 lc rgb '#3274D9' lt 1 lw 0.5 ps 0.3 # pre-agg parameter
set style arrow 1 heads ls 4
```

[image]

Comment: You could try using `pointinterval`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26066299/2604213 for an example

Comment: thanks. indeed it looks better